# type with Maybe props doesn't allow type with Non-Maybe props

Tags: javascript, flowtype

Why does flow throw errors here?

```
type MaybeProp = {
  prop: ?number,
}

type DefinetlyProp = {
  prop: number,
}


const requireMaybe = (u: MaybeProp) => console.log(u)
const requireDefinetly = (u: DefinetlyProp) => requireMaybe(u)
```

https://flow.org/try/#0FDAuE8AcFMAIFkCG4BG0AKAnA9pWBeWAb2Flkh0gC5YB+AOwFcBbNTAGmAF8QIZYAItABmAS3rRQAG3BZcBYqXKUaTVtA7cQwAMbZ6AZ1CxM0AI6NRppKjiEAFIxo20cyAEoCAPlh7D2KWgAOilsAHNHd119IxNzS1MhMQlpcAVHGiTxSRk3T3wfUwsraBdoSKA

It seems like that a function, that can handle maybe properties, should also be able to handle the same properties when they are definetly defined.

Any way to work around this?

Comment: Make them the same type and change the parameter to a "maybe"... https://flow.org/try/#0FDAuE8AcFMAIAUBOB7SsC8sDexa0ipAFywB2ArgLYBG0iANMAL4jADGypAzqLItAEdyAS34BZAIbhaGWAApyJAPxJUASgwA+WB27IANtAB0+5AHMFa9px59BI-gBFoAM2GloofeFkKSqyA10bX4hUWhJaWhLIA

Comment: I'm not calling you dumb... The error occured because you were requesting a type of `MaybeProp` and passing a `DefinitelyProp`... in your second example, you're requesting and passing a number.

Comment: @evolutionxbox
That is obvious. But why does it break when the number is nested? Since flow does not do nominal comparing for objects, it doesn't just blindly look if `MaybeProp !== DefinitelyProp`. It compares the structure.

Comment: @evolutionxbox see https://flow.org/en/docs/lang/nominal-structural/#toc-objects-are-structurally-typed

Comment: @evolutionxbox e.g., I can pass an extra prop
https://flow.org/try/#0FDAuE8AcFMAIFkCG4BG0AKAnA9pWBeWAb2Flkh0gC5YB+AOwFcBbNTAGmAF8QIZYAItABmAS3rRQAG3BZcBYqXKUaTVtA7deUOAFEAHqEyI5eQiTIVcNBizacy0Q8dM0U2bFOiJ6nHiABjbHoAZ1BYTGgAR0ZRSKRUOEIACkYaBLRTAEoCAD5YINDPaAA6KWwAc1Ss4EKwiOjYyKExCWlwBVSaFvFJGWy8hpi46Azoatrg+sjhyIMjRCszWC7YeZdKHPx8mabR5DRqoA

Comment: You make a very good point. Have you raised this on GitHub or whatever tool they use?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is because objects in JS are mutable. As far as the type system is concerned, `requireMaybe` could execute `u.prop = null`. Then, the original caller would be expecting `prop` to be a `number`, but it would actually be `null`. This would break type safety.

You can accomplish what you want to by using [property variance](https://flowtype.org/blog/2016/10/04/Property-Variance.html):

```
type MaybeProp = {
  +prop: ?number,
}

type DefinetlyProp = {
  +prop: number,
}


const requireMaybe = (u: MaybeProp) => console.log(u)
const requireDefinetly = (u: DefinetlyProp) => requireMaybe(u)
```

Comment: Only needed the property variance in the MaybeType. Thank you!